# Hadoop: Having threads inside map function

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, mapreduce

Can i have threads inside map function? I have a task were having threads could really help me. I need to concurrently add values to a hashmap for every input line. My input line becomes an array of string and for every value of this array, i need to add it to the hash map. I later use this hashmap in the cleanup function.

I am doing this with a for loop and it seems that is the bottleneck for my project. So i thought of using a concurrent hash map and splitting the array of strings into several smaller arrays. So every thread would be responsible for adding the corresponding "smaller" array inside the hashmap. The thing is that i have implement it in a local java application and it works. When i use it inside hadoop, the results are not the ones expected. I am using Thread.join() for every thread so that for every line of input i make sure that the threads have finished before the next line. Well that is what i thought i did. Does hadoop treats threads with a special way?

```
   edits for duffymo
```

Here is the google citation http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36296.html .

Algorithm 2 is the part that i am talking about. As you can see there is a for loop for every attribute and that for every attribute i need to update the in memory structure. They only have to predict one value in their approach (single label learning), were in mine i might have many values to predict (multi label learning). So what google says y value, for them is a 3 value array. For me it might be up to thousands. Aggregating two 3-dimension vectors is a lot faster than aggregating two 10000-dimension vectors.

If i put only a single label in my algorithm, i have no problem at all. The 45 seconds i mentioned, are reduced to less than 5. So yes, it is working correctly for one label only.

The 45 seconds i mentioned are for the for-loop only. I didn't count the parsing and all the other things. The for loop is the bottleneck for sure since this is the only thing that i am timing and it takes about 45 seconds, while the whole task takes about 1 minute (including task initialization and many more). I want to try and brake that for-loop into 2 or 3 smaller for loops and process them concurrently. Trying means that it might work and that it might not work. Sometimes crazy stuff like the one i mentioned, could be a necessity. Well that is  what a well respected programmer told me in a previous thread of mine about hadoop.

I didn't provide these many details earlier, since i thought that i only wanted an opinion about hadoop and threads inside the map function. Didn't think that someone would question me so much :P.

Comment: I don't think you understand that "concurrent" doesn't mean "lots of things can happen at the same time".

Comment: if so, then what does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

Hadoop, by itself is built to do parallelism. But it is doing it in very coarse grained manner. Hadoop parallelism is good when dataset is big, and can be divided into many subsets which are processed separately and independently (here I am referring to the Map stage only, for simplicity), for example -to search one pattern in the text. 
Now, lets consider the following case : We have a lot of data, and we want to search 1000's of different patterns in this text. Now we have two choices to utilize our multi-core CPUs. 
1. Process each file using separate mapper in a single thread, and have several mappers per node 
2. Define one mapper per node and process one file by all cores.  
The second way might be much more cache friendly, and thereof to be more efficient. 
In a bottom line - for cases when fine-grained, multi-core friendly parallelism is justified by the nature of processing - usage of multi-threading within mapper can benefit us.

Comment: Yes i think that the second solution is something that may benefit me.  I thought of it to be honest and i was going to ask how to set the configuration files to achieve it, but first i need to find out on how to use threads inside map function. I already mentioned that i managed to use threads to add elements inside a concurrent hashmap in a local java application, but in hadoop the results are not the ones expected. Is there something i need to know about threads and hadoop? Thanks :)

Comment: in best of my knowledge hadoop does not interfere in any way with threads you might spown from within mapper or reducer.

Comment: hmm..maybe i am doing something wrong, since i am totally new to threads.. Anyway thanks again.

Comment: @DavidGruzman Even I didn't find anything where they say Hadoop does not allow or has any interference with us launching a new thread from the map function. Since I landed up here searching for it, could you please update if you found anything regarding this? Or are we correct and Hadoop allows us to launch new threads without any interference?

Comment: Hadoop allow you to launch threads from within you mapper and reducer.  More than that - i would wander if it is technically possible to prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need threads if I understand Hadoop and map/reduce properly.

What makes you think parsing a single line of input is a bottleneck in your project?  Does it merely seem to you that it's an issue or do you have data to prove it?

UPDATE: Thank you for the citation.  It's obviously something that will have to be digested by me and others, so I won't have any snappy advice in the short term.  But I appreciate the citation and your patience very much.

Comment: i am implementing it according to a google paper, so the map/reduce is correct. For every line i might have up to thousands of inserts to a hashmap. Yes i have some data to prove it. For about 1800 lines of input and for 2500 attributes, a map task takes about 45 seconds. That is why i want to try something else, like inserting concurrently. Trying new things is how research works and does not necessarily means that someone is doing something wrong. So can you help me by providing some tips in threads inside map function?

Comment: Please provide the citation to the Google paper.  Sorry, I don't believe your conclusion is correct.  I'll bet the issue is the parsing, not inserting into a map.  If I were to benchmark inserting that many items into a map of any kind right now I'd bet that it wouldn't take 45 seconds.  Maybe you should profile your code and see where the time is being spent.

Comment: See my edits duffymo. Sorry for not providing so many details but i thought that they wouldn't be necessary. Well they weren't necessary for my question but you kept questioning me a lot :P. Thanks for you interest.

Comment: duffymo is right, it is better to let Hadoop parallelize the work for you instead of multithreading it for yourself. There is a multithreaded mapper which can give you some ideas to make it "correct".

Comment: No problem duffymo. Questions means interest. You could simple avoid asking me :P. So thanks again. I will take a look at that Thomas. I know that i shouldn't mix these things together, but since this project is very important for me, i am willing to do anything it takes. The single label implementation is scalable enough. By i need it to be scalable even if i have more labels. I have a feeling that the threads wont provide me a solution either, but i need to try it.